# Data loss in Unity with Updates and IEnumerators

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

So my code is incomplete... but it is also really straightforward.. I figure that if you can answer, you are also aware enough to be able to use Visual Studios Intellisense and auto fill a couple things... sorry, been a long night.

I have three primary scripts... this is the main link in the chain, it passes the data it received through. and onwards.. however, when it is filtering the method it uses for AddToStack(); the output however is...

Sending...1 (x91)
Recieving...1 (x9)

now I have tweaked it and got it flowing 90 to 10 but still.. I don't get why 90% of my data is dropping.. am I screwing up the flow of Unity Engine or something? XD I'm kinda nooby with Unity.

Scripts are as follows:

1.) Primary - Sends data with a delay if dataStrength is less than the threshold and without a delay if it is greater than or equal to the threshold.
2.) uses update method to check if public input is greater than 0 and if so start a method for saving input to a list, then reset the input to 0 for next input. Then when "A" is pressed it iterates through the list and spits out the sum.

SCRIPT ONE (SENDS DATA CONDITIONALLY)

```
private float totalStrength = 0;
public float activationThreshold;
public float signalStrength;
public bool showPackets = true;
public bool showFullDebug = true;
public Stack<float> signals = new Stack<float>();


void Start ()
{
    nodeGrowthThreshold = 60; //Just temporary arbitrary numeric values...
    activationThreshold = 20; //The default values if not set.
    path = GetComponent<Path>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (signalStrength > 0)
    {
        if (numRequests.Equals(nodeGrowthThreshold)) { StartCoroutine(NodeGrow()); StopCoroutine(NodeGrow()); }

        if (totalStrength >= activationThreshold)
        {
            StartCoroutine(AddToStack());
            StopCoroutine(AddToStack());
            signalStrength = 0;
            if (showPackets || showFullDebug) { StartCoroutine(ReadStack()); StopCoroutine(ReadStack()); }
            StartCoroutine(WriteStack());
            StopCoroutine(WriteStack());

            totalStrength -= activationThreshold;
            signalStrength = 0;
            signals.Clear();
        }
        else if (totalStrength < activationThreshold)
        {
            StartCoroutine(AddToStack());
            StopCoroutine(AddToStack());
            signalStrength = 0;
        }


    }
    if (showFullDebug) { print("Node receieved: " + numRequests + " requests."); }
}

private IEnumerator AddToStack()
{
    if (!showFullDebug) { print("Node added signal: " + signalStrength + " to storage stack"); }
    signals.Push(signalStrength);
    numRequests++;
    totalStrength += signalStrength;
    yield return null;
}



private IEnumerator WriteStack()
{
    if (showFullDebug) { print("Node is passing stack of stack size..." + signals.Count); }
    if (signals.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (float signal in signals.ToArray()) { path.input = signal;  if (showFullDebug) { print(signal); } print("Sending... " + signal); /**NOT CAPTURING DATA FAST ENOUGH. DATA IS SENDING FAST ENOUGH THOUGH.**/} }
    yield return null;
}
```

SCRIPT TWO (RECIEVER)

```
public class Out : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float input = 0;
    private float savedOutput = 0;
    public bool showFullDebug = true;
    public List<float> savedInput = new List<float>();
    public Queue<float> output = new Queue<float>();

    private void Update()
    {
        if (input > 0) {
            //StartCoroutine(Save());
            //StopCoroutine(Save());\
            Save();
            input = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A)) { print(savedOutput); }
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        savedInput.Add(input);
        output.Enqueue(input);
        foreach (float num in savedInput.ToArray()) { savedOutput += num; }
        //yield return null;
    }
}
```

Thank you to anyone who can help.

Notes:
- The data I used was obviously just a 1 for a float passed through 100 times for simulation. 
- as you can see, I have attempted IEnumerators and just methods normally... but not sure why data is getting dropped..

Comment: Bumping Because I posted late and it may have got lost in the pile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the best solution to my answer was to use a Setter in my receiving class and set that, that way it does all necessary actions any time it is changed, and not just checking IF it has changed every so often.